# office 365 chat service in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, office365, chat, instant-messaging

In my organization, people use Microsoft Office 365 for mail service.

In Windows system they can setup a chat client with Office 365 and use the instant message service. I'm using Ubuntu and when I searched around the web could not find the option to use Office 365 chat in my machine.  How can I do that?

Error message:

```
No setup available for this computer
Read: Set up your Mac for Office 365
Return to Home
```

Comment: I am going to guess the answer is **you can't** because Microsoft hasn't released a product.  I have no idea what **Ubuntu m/c** please clarify I am sure I am not the only one.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, ubuntu m/c refers to the machine with os as ubuntu.. @Ramhound

Comment: The answer is the same there isn't a chat service client currently produced by Microsoft.  So unless it uses the same network as Windows Live Messenger/Skype currently you are out of luck unless you can find a third-party application written by somebody.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound i also tried from my end looking around compatible applications which did't fetched any results